# dll reference not getting copied into Bin folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I created a Solution with 4 projects in it. 1 Console Application and 3 Class Libraries.

```
Console App Name : MyProject (Dependencies on Common and Domain and Logic)
Class Library 1 : MyProject.Logic (Dependencies on Common and Domain)
Class Library 2 : MyProject.Domain 
Class Library 3 : MyProject.Common
```

Now I add References of `MyProject.Domain` and `MyProject.Common` to `MyProject.Logic` Project 
using `References --> Add Refernce --> Project` and select Refernces

and Added References of `MyProject.Domain`, `MyProject.Common` and `MyProject.Logic` to `MyProject`
using `References --> Add Refernce --> Project` and select Refernces

i Aslo verified Properties of all three references ,they all having `"Copy Local"` set to `True`

When I Build/ Rebuid MyProject , it didn't find references for `MyProject.Common` and `MyProject.Logic` but it gets the Reference for `MyProject.Domain`. Therefore Dll's of `MyProject.Common` and `MyProject.Logic` do not get copied to the bin folder of `MyProject`

I have seen similar forums on web.. but I didn't find any solution.

Anybody have any idea on this??

Comment: Can you verify that the projects `MyProject.Common` and `MyProject.Logic` are themselves able to build without errors?

Comment: Also, if the dlls are referenced but its classes never used, the dll won't be copied to the bin directory

Comment: @mellamokb , yes `MyProject.Common` and `MyProject.Logic` get built successfully...

Comment: @jorgebg , both DLL's method being used in `MyProject`

Comment: At any rate, as long as all of the projects build properly, it should not matter that the referenced dll's are not getting copied into the bin directory.  If you need a dll for another project, always get it only from the bin directory of the source project. i.e., get `MyProject.Common.dll` from the `MyProject.Common/bin` directory, etc.

Comment: @mellamokb, if i manually copy the dlls of MyProject.Common and MyProject.Logic to bin Folder it will work but from my limited knowledge , i think all referenced library get and should automatically coped to bin directory. so project can find it refernces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks All for your replies,

the Proejct --> `MyProject.Common` was using `log4net` assembly and so target framework of `MyProject.Common` was `.Net Framework 4` ,

where as target framework of `MyProject` was `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` .

so i Changed Traget Framework of `MyProject` to `.Net Framework 4` using

Right Click on `MyProject --> Properties --> Application Tab --> Select Target Framework: to .Net Framework 4`

IF anybody have such issue then also check targets of your all projects referenced with same framework.